# How to edit Win32_Product InstallDate using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to edit Win32_Product install date using PowerShell, I tried this script (runned as Administrator):

```
$tmp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName . | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -eq "Software Name"}
$tmp.InstallDate="20170305"
$tmp.put()
```

But it is telling me there is missing arguments in put().
I checked and the $tmp content the good Object, but I can't edit it.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378.aspx):

> InstallDate
>
> Data type: string
>       Access type: ***Read-only***

Emphasis mine.

If you must fake the install date (for whatever obscure reason) you must do so directly in the registry.

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\path\to\uninstall\key' 'InstallDate' '20170305'
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but when I edit registry and then get the WmiObject, I still have the same date, even if the InstallDate registry entry is changed

Comment: @user2663781 The simple answer is to stop using `Win32_Product` and query the reg key each time anyways. Every time you call the WMI class, it does a verification on every installed msi....

Comment: Indeed, [`Win32_Product` is evil](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/) and should be avoided entirely.

Comment: ^ He is correct, never use `Win32_Product`. [Query the registry instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575378/powershell-for-software-inventory/71576041#71576041) for your software inventory needs.